# Splitting a list into a 2 dimensional list

Tags: python, list

Given a list with several names as a parameter, I was wondering if there was a way to split the names by first and last and create a 2d list of all first names and all last names. For example given:

```
lst=(["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"])
```

the output should be:

```
[["Leonoardo","Brad","Angelina"],["DiCaprio","Pitt","Jolie"]]
```

I know that I need to iterate over the given list, and append the first names and last names to a new lists but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. 
This is what I've got so far:

```
fname=[]
lname=[]
for i in nlst:
    i.split()
fname.append(i[0])
lname.append(i[1])  
return lname,fname
```

Comment: The `( )` around `(["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"])` may mislead you into thinking that is a tuple; it isn't. You may want to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> lst=(["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"])
>>> new = [[item.split(',')[1] for item in lst], [item.split(',')[0] for item in lst]]
>>> new
[['Leonardo', ' Brad', ' Angelina'], ['DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie']]
```

Or you can `zip` it:

```
>>> x = [item.split(',') for item in lst]
>>> list(reversed(zip(*x)))
[('Leonardo', ' Brad', ' Angelina'), ('DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split and transpose:

```
lst = ["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"]

print([list(ele) for ele in zip(*(ele.split(",") for ele in lst))])
```

Or use map:

```
print(list(map(list, zip(*(ele.split(",") for ele in lst)))))

[['DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie'], ['Leonardo', ' Brad', ' Angelina']]
```

If you need the order reversed:

```
print(list(map(list, zip(*(reversed(ele.split(",")) for ele in lst)))))

[['Leonardo', ' Brad', ' Angelina'], ['DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie']]
```

For python2 you can use izip and the remove the list call on map:

```
from itertools import izip
print(map(list, izip(*(reversed(ele.split(",")) for ele in lst))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
list_names = []
list_last =[]
lst=["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"]
for element in lst:

   list_names.append(element.split(',')[0])
   list_last.append(element.split(',')[1])
```

Let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function :

```
>>> l=["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"]
>>> zip(*[i.split(',') for i in l])[::-1]
[('Leonardo', ' Brad', ' Angelina'), ('DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie')]
```

If you want the result as list you can convert to list with `map` function :

```
>>> map(list,zip(*[i.split(',') for i in l])[::-1])
[['Leonardo', ' Brad', ' Angelina'], ['DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie']]
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham did you mean why tuple? ;)  . OP doesn't consist in `list`.!

Comment: No I mean why build a list, you would also need to map to list as in my answer, the OP wants a lists of lists not tuples

Answer (score 0):

a function to return the names after splitting.

```
def split_list(the_list=["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"]):
    list_2d = [[],[]]
    for full_name in the_list:
        first_name, second_name = full_name.split(',')
        list_2d[0].append(first_name)
        list_2d[1].append(second_name)
    return list_2d

print split_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

According your code, you can try this:

```
lst=(["DiCaprio,Leonardo","Pitt, Brad", "Jolie, Angelina"])
fname=[]
lname=[]
for i in lst:
   fname.append(i.split(",")[0])
   lname.append(i.split(",")[1])  

print [lname,fname]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+),\s*(\w+);?', ';'.join(lst)) 
[('DiCaprio', 'Leonardo'), ('Pitt', 'Brad'), ('Jolie', 'Angelina')]
```

Then use either `zip` or `map` to transpose the list of tuples:

```
>>> map(None, *re.findall(r'(\w+),\s*(\w+);?', ';'.join(lst))) 
[('DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie'), ('Leonardo', 'Brad', 'Angelina')]
```

On Python 3, you can't use map that way. Instead, you would do:

```
>>> list(map(lambda *x: [e for e in x], *re.findall(r'(\w+),\s*(\w+);?', ';'.join(lst))))
```

Then reverse the order and make a list of lists rather than list of tuples if you wish:

```
>>> lot=map(None, *re.findall(r'(\w+),\s*(\w+);?', ';'.join(lst)))
>>> [list(lot[1]), list(lot[0])]
[['Leonardo', 'Brad', 'Angelina'], ['DiCaprio', 'Pitt', 'Jolie']]
```